# Do predictions produce predicates?

Tags: word-request

For example estimation produces estimates (values). In an analogy, does prediction produce predicates?

I do not know how to correctly call data produced by predictions.

Comment: He who estimates produces an estimation. He who predicts produces a prediction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, predictions can mean both the process and the result.

> We will do a prediction in order to guess next week's weather.
>
> Here are our latest predictions about this week's weather !

In any case, a predicate doesn't mean that at all. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate